# Do passive bonuses from followers remain even while the follower is dead?

Tags: diablo-iii

Do followers passive bonuses like [Templar's Loyalty](http://d3db.com/skill/i/loyalty) or [Scoundrel's Hysteria](http://d3db.com/skill/i/hysteria) still works while a follower is "dead"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, they do not work if follower is dead.

> Followers will not stay alive easily past Normal, and if they're not
>   alive you aren't going to be getting their bonuses.

It has been designed in this way to discourage their usage at higher level difficulties. By design their role is to let players get used to play with others at Normal difficulty, and substitute followers with "human" players at highest difficulties.

[Source](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/official-followers-page-plus-blue-answers)

Comment: Thank you for citing the source. Good to know the templar isn't a reliable source of regeneration for my build :)